# Ubuntu 18, unable to install xelatex

Tags: pdf, latex, texlive

I'm trying to install xelatex using

```
sudo apt install texlive-xetex
```

but I'm getting these errors.

```
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 texlive-latex-base all 2017.20180305-1                                                                                                         
  403  Forbidden [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-base/texlive-latex-base_2017.20180305-1_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]                                        
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have already tried running `apt-get update` and with `--fix-missing` flag but it didn't solve the issue.

Can somebody please tell me how to go about this. I'm a newbie ubuntu user.

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine from here. Try again, and if it still doesn't work, try another mirror.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Are you able to install other packages, is the problem specific to the texlive-xetex package?

Comment: Are you using a corporate or school network that may require use of a proxy?

Comment: This was an issue pertaining to this package only.  I was finally able to install it by disabling the firewall settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Forbidden [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
```

You seem to be behind some firewall, that doesn't allow you to reach Ubuntu repositories. You need to check your ISP and/or change Ubuntu mirror.